# Scatter plot with markers changing size according to number of represented points

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I'm plotting a simple scatter plot:
[image: Current plot]

It represents my data correctly, however there is many datapoints with coordinates (1.00,1.00) and in the plot, they appear under a single marker (top right corner). I'd like to have a functionality that changes the size of every marker according to the number of points it is representing. Will appreciate any help. Here's my code:

```
def saveScatter(figureTitle, xFeature, yFeature, xTitle, yTitle):
''' save a scatter plot of xFeatures vs yFeatures '''

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=300)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    
    ax.scatter(dfModuleCPositives[names[xFeature]][:], dfModuleCPositives[names[yFeature]][:], c='r', marker='x', alpha=1, label='Module C Positives')
    ax.scatter(dfModuleCNegatives[names[xFeature]][:], dfModuleCNegatives[names[yFeature]][:], c='g', alpha=0.5, label='Module C Negatives')
    ax.scatter(dfModuleDPositives[names[xFeature]][:], dfModuleDPositives[names[yFeature]][:], c='k', marker='x', alpha=1, label='Module D Positives')
    ax.scatter(dfModuleDNegatives[names[xFeature]][:], dfModuleDNegatives[names[yFeature]][:], c='b', alpha=0.5, label='Module D Negatives')    
    ax.set_xlabel(xTitle, fontsize=10)
    ax.set_ylabel(yTitle, fontsize=10)
    ax.set_title(figureTitle)
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.legend(loc="lower right")
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    return ax
```

Comment: There is an `s` keyword argument for the scatter method which lets you adjust marker size that you should look at. With your current framework, it might require significant reworking to integrate though

Comment: Do you have example data, even if it is a few lines?